# How to use nodelets on ubuntu 14.04 ros indigo and packages hector-quadrotor-pose-estimation,ros-indigo-camera1394 or ros-indigo-stereo-image-proc

Tags: ros, camera1394, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I've used nodelets on ubuntu 12.04 and ros hydro without any problems. After updating ubuntu and ros some files seem to be missing. For example, when I try to use the hector_pose_estimation_nodelet this error occures:

> Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/hector_pose_estimation/hector_pose_estimation_nodelets.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.

The file simply doesn't exist.
My temporary workaround is to download the packages to my workspace and compile them myself:

> apt-get source ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-pose-estimation 
> apt-get source ros-indigo-camera1394 
> apt-get source ros-indigo-stereo-image-proc

By doing this everything works just fine, as the nodelet description xml is found (in my workspace) then.
That made me wonder if I did something wrong, or if the packages are corrupt.
Other packages, that use nodelets seem to contain and install the xml descirption files - for example openni:

> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-openni-camera/ros-indigo-openni-camera_1.9.2-1trusty-20141104-2335-+0000_amd64.deb

But the packages I use don't contain any xml - for example:

> http://packages.ros.org/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-pose-estimation/ros-indigo-hector-quadrotor-pose-estimation_0.3.3-0trusty-20141105-0951-+0000_amd64.deb

I couln't find anyone with similar problems out there, thus I ask my questions here:

Did I something wrong?
Are nodelets used a different way in ros indigo?
Are these packages corrupt?
Where can I report a bug in one of these packages?

Sincerely Yours
Bernd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199246/how-to-use-nodelets-on-ubuntu-14.04-ros-indigo-and-packages-hector-quadrotor-pose-estimation,ros-indigo-camera1394-or-ros-indigo-stereo-image-proc/) by [KastB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21076/kastb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-12-10**:
The camera1394 nodelet file should be in `/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera1394/camera1394_nodelet.xml`. Is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the case of camera1394, the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394) includes the usual [link for reporting bugs](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/issues).

This problem has not been previously reported for Indigo. It was [reported and fixed](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/issues/10) in Hydro.

Looking at the source code, [CmakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L63) *does* still install [camera1394_nodelet.xml](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/camera1394_nodelet.xml), and has since [#10](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/issues/10) was fixed in release 1.9.4.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0